# How to ignore specific fields on income in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have my domain class as follows

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student {

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

And I have this controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Student> post(@RequestBody Student student) {
        //todo save student info in db, it get's an auto-generated id
        return new ResponseEntity<>(student, HttpStatus.CREATED);        
    }

}
```

Now what I want is to configure serializer in a way that it ignores the `id` field on income, so I get only `firstName` and `lastName`, but serialize it when I'm returning the object to the caller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its easy to use it with jackson. There is an annotation named `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` where you can define if the property should be de- or serialized. Just put that annotation on your `id` field.

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private Long id;
```

The Controller:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Student> post(@RequestBody Student student) {

    //here we will see the that id is not deserialized
    System.out.println(student.toString());

    //here we set a new Id to the student.
    student.setId(123L);

    //in the response we will see that student will serialized with an id.
    return new ResponseEntity<>(student, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Requestbody:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "firstName": "Patrick",
    "lastName" : "secret"
}
```

Output of toString():

```
Student [id=null, firstName=Patrick, lastName=secret]
```

Response:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "firstName": "Patrick",
    "lastName": "secret"
}
```

P.S. It will also work if you dont send an id property:

```
{
    "firstName": "Patrick",
    "lastName" : "secret"
}
```